# How to solve this Depth first search problem?

Tags: c, function, recursion, graph, depth-first-search

So I need to do a depth first search traversal of a given graph, however if a node in the graph has multiple adjacent neighbours, I need to choose the node with the lowest value to go to. So I implemented the following recursive depth first search function:

```
void DFS(struct Graph *graph, int vertex) {
    struct node *adjList = graph->adjLists[vertex];
    struct node *temp = adjList;

    graph->visited[vertex] = 1;
    printf("Visited %d \n", vertex);
  
    int neighbouring_nodes[graph->numVertices];
  
    while (temp != NULL) {
        int count = 0;
        struct node *temp_cpy = temp;
     
        while (temp_cpy != NULL) {
            neighbouring_nodes[count] = temp_cpy->vertex;
            count++;
            temp_cpy = temp_cpy->next;
        }

        int smallest_node = neighbouring_nodes[0];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            if (neighbouring_nodes[i] < smallest_node) {
                smallest_node = neighbouring_nodes[i];
            }
        }
    
        if (graph->visited[smallest_node] == 0) {
            DFS(graph, smallest_node);
        } else if (graph->visited[smallest_node] == 1 && count == 1) {
            //if the node is visited but is it the only neighbour
            DFS(graph, smallest_node);
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

But when I run my program, it results in an infinite loop. I think I know why I am getting an infinite loop, it might be because there is never a return condition, so the recursive function just keeps running?

Is this type of depth first search possible with a recursive function? If yes, where am I going wrong? If no, how would I do it iteratively?
Help would be much appreciated.

Below is my full program without the DFS function:

```
// DFS algorithm in C

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int vertex;
    struct node *next;
};

struct node *createNode(int v);

struct Graph {
    int numVertices;
    int *visited;
    struct node **adjLists;
};

// Create a node
struct node *createNode(int v) {
    struct node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->vertex = v;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

// Create graph
struct Graph *createGraph(int vertices) {
    struct Graph *graph = malloc(sizeof(struct Graph));
    graph->numVertices = vertices;

    graph->adjLists = malloc(vertices * sizeof(struct node*));

    graph->visited = malloc(vertices * sizeof(int));

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < vertices; i++) {
        graph->adjLists[i] = NULL;
        graph->visited[i] = 0;
    }
    return graph;
}

// Add edge
void addEdge(struct Graph *graph, int src, int dest) {
    // Add edge from src to dest
    struct node *newNode = createNode(dest);
    newNode->next = graph->adjLists[src];
    graph->adjLists[src] = newNode;

    // Add edge from dest to src
    newNode = createNode(src);
    newNode->next = graph->adjLists[dest];
    graph->adjLists[dest] = newNode;
}

// Print the graph
void printGraph(struct Graph *graph) {
    int v;
    for (v = 0; v < graph->numVertices; v++) {
        struct node *temp = graph->adjLists[v];
        printf("\n Adjacency list of vertex %d\n ", v);
        while (temp) {
            printf("%d -> ", temp->vertex);
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    struct Graph *graph = createGraph(4);
    addEdge(graph, 0, 1);
    addEdge(graph, 0, 2);
    addEdge(graph, 1, 2);
    addEdge(graph, 2, 3);

    printGraph(graph);

    DFS(graph, 2);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Is DFS possible with recursive function?" - yes. I notice that you do revisit a node if it is the only node. Are you sure about that? If it is the only node, then all routes from there should have been considered when you visited the first time.

Comment: Aside - Shouldn't the declaration: `int smallest_node = ...` be moved outside the `while(){...}` loop?

Comment: @WeatherVane I removed that else statement, but my function still doesnt work

Comment: The `struct Graph` contains no member `adjLists`.  But the code shown has this:  `graph->adjLists = malloc(vertices * sizeof(struct node*));`.  Double check and edit to ensure the posted code is what you are actually using

Comment: Why do you need to choose the lowest value to go to, and not explore all routes? One route from node A to node B might be three steps 1+1+1 and another might be one step of 2. There might be a time problem exploring every route, but you would abandon a route once it becomes more expensive (or eventually cannot be less) than the best one so far. Also caching can dramatically reduce the search space.

Comment: @ryyker have updated my code. should contain all members.

Comment: Have you compiled with warnings turned up?   Eg, in `gcc` use `-Wall`.   When you do, go through each one (errors too of course) and address them all before expecting anything to work right.

Comment: @ryyker yes I have compiled with warnings turned up, no compiler errors in my end, what errors are you getting?

Comment: None after your most recent edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I came up with:

```
void DFS(struct Graph* graph, int vertex) {
    struct node* temp = graph->adjLists[vertex];

    graph->visited[vertex] = 1;
    printf("Visited %d \n", vertex);

    int neighbouring_nodes[graph->numVertices];

    int count = 0;

    while(temp != NULL) {
        neighbouring_nodes[count] = temp->vertex;
        count++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    int smallest_node = neighbouring_nodes[0];
    
    //   Need to search (at most) in every neighbouring node
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        //   Go through all nodes in neighbouring_nodes array in order
        //   to find the smallest unvisited one, if it exists
        for (int j = 0; j < count; j++){
            //   if current smallest_node has already been visited and
            //   neighbouring_nodes[j] is unvisited, assign it to smallest_node
            if (graph->visited[smallest_node] == 1 && graph->visited[neighbouring_nodes[j]] == 0){
                    smallest_node = neighbouring_nodes[j];
            }
            //   if neighbouring_nodes[j] is smaller than smallest_node,
            //   assign it to smallest_node
            if (graph->visited[neighbouring_nodes[j]] == 0 && neighbouring_nodes[j] < smallest_node){
                smallest_node = neighbouring_nodes[j];
            }
        }
        if (graph->visited[smallest_node] == 0){
            //   calls DFS on the smallest unvisited neighboring node, if it exists
            DFS(graph, smallest_node);
        }else{
            //   otherwise (all neighboring nodes already visited)
            //   return control to the caller function
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not 100% sure I understood what you wanted to do with the `while (temp != NULL)` and `while (temp_cpy != NULL)` loops but couldn't really figure out a way to use this approach especially in your particular case in which you want to visit the neighboring nodes in ascending order.

Let's assume a simple graph like `6->0->1`, calling `DFS(g, 0)` will get `temp` to point to `6->1->NULL` (could be also `1->6->NULL`, depending on how you construct the graph), then `smallest_node` will be `1` and therefore the node 1 will be visited and the `temp = temp->next` will "assign" `1->NULL` to `temp`. Back to the beginning of the loop, now `temp_cpy` will "be equal" to `temp`, hence `1->NULL`. The node `6` is not on the list anymore even if it was not visited, on the other hand the already visited node `1` is still there. Also `count` is now equal to `1` therefore the condition `(graph->visited[smallest_node] == 1 && count == 1)` is met and `DFS(g, 1)` is called, which should not since node `1` was already visited. The infinite loop arises from this, since the previous condition is always met when `temp` has one (already visited) element left (`[some value]->NULL`). Once you reach that point you always call `DFS(g, [some value])` and this will never give back control, since before reaching the `temp = temp->next` statement (which should assign `NULL` to `temp` , hence ending the while loop), `DFS(g, [some other value])` is again called, which at some point will again call `DFS(g, [some value])`, and so forth.

As mentioned, one problem your original code has is that you call the `DFS` function also for an already visited vertex, and this should never be the case. When you encounter an already visited neighboring vertex, you want either to check the next or, if there are no unvisited neighboring vertices left, to give back control to the caller function. Therefore the last `if else` statement should not be there. The second problem is that `smallest_node` is selected in the wrong way. This is because `temp_cpy`, as explained above, is not constructed in such a way that it necessarily contains all unvisited neighboring nodes and also because you're actually looking for the smallest element in this list, regardless if it has already been visited or not (again because of the assumption that `temp_cpy` contains only all unvisited nodes). In fact you should be looking for the "smallest unvisited node" rather than the "smallest node".

In my code I go through all neighboring nodes with two `for` loops, find the smallest unvisited one and call `DFS(g, [smallest unvisited node])` and once there are no unvisited neighbors left, `return` control back to the caller function.

I Hope this is somewhat understandable and I also hope I'm not missing something about what you had in mind with your implementation, in which case I would be very much interested in some explanations!

Here is a simpler version of the `DFS` in which neighboring nodes are checked and eventually visited in the order they're presented in the `adjList`. In this case I think the `while (temp != NULL)`/`temp = temp->next` approach makes sense:

```
void DFS(struct Graph *graph, int vertex) {
    struct node *temp = graph->adjLists[vertex];

    graph->visited[vertex] = 1;
    printf("Visited %d \n", vertex);

    //   for vertex search in every neighboring node
    while (temp != NULL) {
        //   if neighboring vertex temp->vertex not visited, then search there
        if (graph->visited[temp->vertex] == 0) {
            DFS(graph, temp->vertex);
        //   if already visited, go to the next vertex on the neighbors list
        }else{
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    // when searched in all neighboring vertexes return control to caller
    return;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome! I also think that ravenspoint is right about the already ordered lists of neighboring nodes. You could try to write an ```addEdgeAscending``` function that takes care of placing the new node at the "right" place in the list.

Answer (score 2):

"if a node in the graph has multiple adjacent neighbours, I need to choose the node with the lowest value to go to."

I assume the 'value' of a node is an attribute of the node object?

Most implementations of DFS will first look at the node with the lowest index in the data structure containing the node objects.  So, if you first sort the nodes in your data structure into ascending value order, then the DFS will do what you want without needing to change the DFS code.